# Error using Oracle Instant Client Docker image

Tags: linux, oracle, docker, dockerfile, alpine-linux

our app is nodejs based and needs to query Oracle DB, so we install NPM oracledb package. So our Docker image is based on  [oracle instant client](https://hub.docker.com/r/asg1612/alpine-oracle-instantclient), the Docker file looks like following:

```
FROM frolvlad/alpine-glibc

RUN apk update && apk add libaio

COPY instantclient_12_1.zip ./
RUN unzip instantclient_12_1.zip
RUN  mv instantclient_12_1/ /usr/lib/
RUN  rm instantclient_12_1.zip
RUN  ln /usr/lib/instantclient_12_1/libclntsh.so.12.1         /usr/lib/libclntsh.so
RUN ln /usr/lib/instantclient_12_1/libocci.so.12.1 /usr/lib/libocci.so
RUN ln /usr/lib/instantclient_12_1/libociei.so /usr/lib/libociei.so
RUN ln /usr/lib/instantclient_12_1/libnnz12.so /usr/lib/libnnz12.so

ENV ORACLE_BASE /usr/lib/instantclient_12_1
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/lib/instantclient_12_1
ENV TNS_ADMIN /usr/lib/instantclient_12_1
ENV ORACLE_HOME /usr/lib/instantclient_12_1

RUN apk add nodejs npm

RUN mkdir -p /var/app
WORKDIR /var/app
ADD package.json /var/app
COPY . /var/app

CMD ["npm","start"]
```

But when our app starts using 'oracledb' NPM package, it got following error:

```
init() error: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "Error loading shared library libnsl.so.1: No such file or directory (needed by /usr/lib/libclntsh.so)". See https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#linux for help Node-oracledb installation instructions: https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html
You must have 64-bit Oracle client libraries in LD_LIBRARY_PATH, or configured with ldconfig.
If you do not have Oracle Database on this computer, then install the Instant Client Basic or Basic Light package from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html
```

So Oracle client couldn't find libnsl.so.1 even thought it should come with glibc, and I can see that it is under:
**'/usr/glibc-compat/lib'.**
Any ideas how to fix this? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
# 1. Install dependencies
FROM node:8.15 as cache-package

COPY package.json /srv/src/package.json
WORKDIR /srv/src

RUN yarn install

# 2. 
FROM node:8.15 as builder

# 1. Update everything on the box
RUN apt-get update && \
      apt-get install sudo
#RUN apk --update add libaio bc net-tools
RUN sudo apt-get install unzip
RUN sudo apt-get install wget
RUN sudo apt-get install git

# 3. Install oracle client
RUN mkdir -p /opt/oracle
# 3.1 Get oracle client
WORKDIR /opt/oracle

RUN wget -O /opt/oracle/instantclient_18_3_linux.zip http://YOUR_URL_TO_DOWNLOAD_THE_CLIENT/instantclient_18_3_linux.zip
RUN sudo unzip /opt/oracle/instantclient_18_3_linux.zip

# 3.2 Configure oracle client to work with node
RUN sudo sh -c "echo /opt/oracle/instantclient_18_3_linux > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-instantclient.conf"
RUN sudo cat /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-instantclient.conf



FROM node:8.15

RUN apt-get update && \
      apt-get install sudo
RUN sudo apt-get install libaio1

RUN mkdir -p /srv/src/logs
RUN mkdir -p /srv/logs
RUN mkdir -p /opt/oracle

# 4. Set the working directory

# 5. Copy our project & install our dependencies
COPY --from=cache-package /srv/src /srv/src

COPY --from=builder /opt/oracle/instantclient_18_3_linux /opt/oracle/instantclient_18_3_linux
COPY --from=builder /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-instantclient.conf /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-instantclient.conf

RUN sudo ldconfig

RUN ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/WET /etc/localtime

COPY . /srv/src

WORKDIR /srv/src

# 6. Start the app
CMD yarn start
```

Here is my dockerfile working fine, the srv/src is my directory where I have my code, just change for yours and it should work.

I have the same problem as you the past two days and now it works.